# uninitialized constant SampleApp (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
/Users/josh/Desktop/RoR/rails_app/config/initializers/secret_token.rb:27:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant SampleApp (NameError)
```

Here's my secret_token.rb file

```
require 'securerandom'

def secure_token
  token_file = Rails.root.join('.secret')
  if File.exist?(token_file)
    # Use the existing token.
    File.read(token_file).chomp
  else
    # Generate a new token and store it in token_file.
    token = SecureRandom.hex(64)
    File.write(token_file, token)
    token
  end
end

SampleApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = secure_token
```

Comment: What's in `Rakefile`? I wanna just check if the App name matches.

Comment: Is your app called SampleApp, or is it called RailsApp?

Comment: Compare name of your app in `config/application.rb`. It's probably differs from `SampleApp`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably change the name of your Rails application.

Check in `config/application.rb` that the name of your application is the same that the one use in your `secret_token.rb` file:

```
SampleApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = secure_token
^^^^^^^^^
```

You should have the following in `config/application.rb`:

```
# ...
module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...
```